# Automatically insert double brace to preserve capital letter in title field of latex bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, automation, capitalization

Surfing on the web, it is clear that double brace in `.bib` item will preserve the capital letters of the titles.

Context: I already have a huge `.bib` with no double brace in the `title` field.

Question: Is there a way of automatically insert the double brace to preserve the capital letter in the title field?

I did a python script that does the dirty job. I am wondering if some built-in function or TeXstudio macro already supports this possibility.

Comment: I don't believe so (not sure, though), but, as far as I remember, you would have no problem with `biblatex`.

Comment: Please don't blanket-protect everything with double braces. Only protect stuff that must remain capitalised (names, acronyms, maths, ...) with braces. Of course that needs careful consideration, so probably human effort and not a script.

Comment: I have the original copy of the file and I use git, so no problem of messing up the latex project. I am trying to understand which is the best option. Moreover, I am using a journal template. So that means that I do not need to touch and care about these details. Possibly, the template editor already took into account this stuff, isn't it?

Comment: Note that changing the case of titles is _not_ built in to bibtex, it is a style choice of the bibliography style that you have chosen.  If you corrupt the `.bib` file with extra `{}` then your citations will not follow the specified house style when used with journal publications, which can lead to problems and delay. So here you should chose a bibtex style that treats titles as you wish, or possibly modify the one you are using to make a variant that doesn't case-change titles. Or just go with the flow and do what the journal wants, even if you don't like the style.

Comment: @Bernard I don't see bibtex or biblatex would be any different here, in both the choice to change case is a matter of the bibliography style chosen. The details of how to customise things are different but the issue is the same.

Comment: all these comments clarify all the doubts! Thank you and thanks to the whole community! If you want to write your advice as an answer, I think can be useful for someone else in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that changing the case of titles is not built into BibTeX, it is a style choice of the bibliography style that you have chosen. If you corrupt the .bib file with extra `{` `}` then your citations will not follow the specified house style when used with journal publications, which can lead to problems and delays.

As commented, only protect stuff that must remain capitalized (names, acronyms, maths, ...) with braces. Of course, that needs careful consideration, so probably human effort and not a script.

So here you should choose a BibTeX style that treats titles as you wish, or possibly modify the one you are using to make a variant that doesn't case-change titles. Or just go with the flow and do what the journal wants, even if you don't like the style.